# How to get query output in addition to EXPLAIN ANALYZE output?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output (e.g. as a notice) in addition to the regular query output?

I am designing a [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) client and I would like to add a feature that automatically turns all queries into `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the purpose of tracking query execution time, seq scan, etc. However, such feature would require that I am able to obtain the regular query output in addition to the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output.

How to get query output in addition to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output?

Note: I am aware of `auto_explain`. However, there appears to be no way to access logs from the client for the last executed statement.

Answer (score 1):

Client can be configured to receive the `auto_explain` message by setting `client_min_messages=log`.

Example configuration:

```
-- Load the extension.
LOAD 'auto_explain';
-- or (if you are using AWS RDS):
LOAD '$libdir/plugins/auto_explain';

-- Enable logging of all queries.
SET auto_explain.log_analyze=true;
SET auto_explain.log_format=json;
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration=0;
SET auto_explain.log_timing=true;

-- Enables Slonik to capture auto_explain logs.
SET client_min_messages=log;
```

with this configuration, client will receive `auto_explain` log message after every query.

[node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) client [Slonik uses this configuration to associate `auto_explain` messages with the specific queries and parse the log messages](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#logging-auto_explain).